# WooCommerce - Custom emails per product

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I need to create custom emails based on product and trigger them on the different events if possible. Most importantly once the customer purchases the product.

Does anyone know of a plugin or a way to do this?

Thank you

Comment: You need to create your own [custom emails](https://www.skyverge.com/blog/how-to-add-a-custom-woocommerce-email/) or hire someone to write the code for you.

Comment: I think i have a solution @helgatheviking, but am still to send the email. I found a plugin that WooThemes offer, called "Follow up emails". It allows you to set up emails to be sent X number of minutes/days/weeks/months/years after a product is purchased. Which works perfect for what i need. Thank you for your help though!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes, for me the Follow up emails from WooThemes is the plugin that solved this.